# Compling with FB 4 or FB 4.5 doesn't give the same result

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder

I found that compiling the same project either in Flash Builder 4 or Flash Builder 4.5 with the sdk 4.1 doesn't give me the same result.

If compiled with flash builder 4, the resulting swf is 1021 KB. If compiled with fb 4.5, it is 1477 KB.

I used the exact same library, sdk and compiling option in both case.

Anybody has an idea ?

Comment: Can you publish `.actionScriptProperties` files of both projects?

Comment: Flash Builder can often mask certain compiler options; such as RSLs.  Are you sure you don't have a library set to be external in FB4 and merged into code for FB45?

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
-dump-config myapp-config.xml
```

to your compiler options and then compare the files. FB4 likely has different defaults for some settings than FB4.5

---

see the docs for [dump-config](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fca.html)